# RecylerView and Paging adapter doesn't work properly

Tags: android

I create an app to fetch some data from the REST API. I had some issues with recycler view scrolling. When I scroll down and then scroll up all the items will be messed up. I searched in stack overflow and find an answer. The answer said that we should add                 setHasStableIds = true to our adapter and add getItemViewType to our adapter class. I did and it worked fine but the new problem came.
the image of the items should load sequentially. For instance, if the user scrolled down to item 200 he/she should wait until all previous items load it images.
This is my adapter code

```
class MovieAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<Movie,MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback()) {


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    try {
        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!)
    }catch (e : Exception){

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {

    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item,parent,false)
    return MovieViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

/////
class MovieViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    private val imgMoviePoster = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imgImagePoster)
    private val txtMovieTitle = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtMovieTitle)
    private val txtMovieReleaseDate = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtMovieReleaseDate)

    fun bind(movie : Movie){
        txtMovieTitle.text = movie.title
        txtMovieReleaseDate.text = movie.releaseDate
        val moviePosterUrl = POSTER_BASE_URL + movie.posterPath

        /*Glide.with(imgMoviePoster)
            .load(moviePosterUrl)
            .into(imgMoviePoster)*/

        Picasso.get().load(moviePosterUrl).into(imgMoviePoster)
    }

}
/////
class DiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movie>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
        return newItem.id == oldItem.id
    }
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
        return newItem == oldItem
    }
}
```

}
This is my code for recycler view and view model (inside main activity)

```
  private fun initRecyclerView(){
    recyclerViewPopMovie.apply {
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity,2)
        movieAdapter = MovieAdapter()
        adapter = movieAdapter
    }
}
private fun initViewModel(){
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        viewModel.getContent().collectLatest {
            movieAdapter.submitData(it)
            movieAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add implementation of recyclerview code. (Fragment/Activity)

Comment: @charlie.7 I added